# Backbone JS Single Page Application file upload?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, single-page-application, mustache

I'm looking for some design patterns or best practices around uploading files from a form to a REST end point.

The REST endpoint is already working and I can POST files to it. Any thoughts would really be appreciated.

Comment: Is this that you're looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161524/how-use-jquery-file-upload-with-backbone-js-require-js/25163019#25163019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
var FileUploadView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #submit": function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '%YOUR_URL%',
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this.$('#form')[0]),
            });
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html("<form id='form'><input type='file' /><input id='submit' value='Upload File' type='button' /></form>");
    }
};
```

Comment: This is how I've ended up doing it but it just felt messy. I'm coming from a few months on AngularJS development and I was hoping for a more elegant solution.